# Reading variables in a text file and ignoring the comments on the same line in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following batch script (see example c below) to read the contents of a text file 
and use the variables in a number of batch files; which is working ok.

The issue is the formatting of file.txt.  I'd like to have it if possible in example A format below;
however it's currently formatted as shown in example B.

**Example A** (preferred formatting of file.txt)

```
VALUE|COMMENT ON VALUE's PURPOSE
```

- value to be read into the script
- End of value/line character (ie a |@!% etc anything post this character is ignored by the script)
- Followed by comments about the value's purpose

**Example B** (current formatting of file.txt)

```
server1
C:
10.10.10.1
::Comments
::name of server
::remote server IP address
::drive the application is installed on
```

**Example C** (Cut down version of the batch file being used for your reference)

```
:: SET VARIABLES FROM "file.txt"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (file.txt) do (
  set /a N+=1
  set v[!N!]=%%a
)

::variables
set VER=%v[5]%
set SRVDRV=%v[6]%
```

etc...

Hopefully this is possible as it would make file.txt easier to read/update/deploy going 
forward especially as we add more scripts to this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the delims option in the FOR /F loop.
This will take the first token up to the first pipe character

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%a in (file.txt) do (
...
```

Comment: Hi Jeb - that has worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for - appreciate the prompt response.